# Windows batch script to go through folders, cd and run program with parameters

Tags: batch-file

Although sounds simple i am bit stumped.
starting from the C drive, I want to cd in to every folder beginning with AM_*\new and then run a program eg "abc.exe PAR1 PAR2"

Comment: recursive or only for folders on level 1?

Comment: so it would go something like this...
cd c:\am_1\new
abc.exe par1 par2
cd c:\am_2\new
abc.exe par1 par2
etc

Comment: So want you `for` each `/D` folder in `AM_*` do a `cd "%%f\new"`, run `abc.exe PAR1 PAR2` and go back to `cd ..`?

Comment: Aacini - basically yes

Comment: The best I have come up with is:
for /D %%f in (c:\am_*) do cd %%f\run
abc.exe par1 par2

The problem is i can see it running through and cd into every folder correctly matching the criteria, but the command is only running in the last folder.

Comment: `for /D %%f in (c:\am_*) do (cd "%%~Ff\run" & abc.exe par1 par2)`

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i managed it ...

```
for /D %%f in (m:\am_*) do (  
cd %%f\run  
abc.exe par1 par2  
)
```

Comment: `run`?  Your question asked for directory `new`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /S /B /AD ^| findstr /R "AM_.*\new') do (
    pushd %%a
    abc.exe something-something
    popd
)
```

How Bow Dat?

Comment: Typo in `'dir /S /B /AD ^| findstr /R "AM_.*\new'`? By [FINDSTR - Escapes and Length limits](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html), it should be `'dir /S /B /AD ^| findstr /I /R "AM_.*\\new"'`

Comment: I would think you would want to use the $ to match at the end of the line. Otherwise it would continue parse sub folders that match that expression.

Comment: I tested with a single **\\**, and it worked fine for me.   If you think you need a double **\\\\**... well, go right ahead.

Comment: Yes but you need to escape the backslash other wise you will match root folders that have the word new in them.  Your code will match these two instances. **C:\AM_asnew** and **C:\AM_1234\new**.  If you escape the backslash it will only match **C:\AM_1234\new**